# Manhwa where a girl becomes the villainess, goes to school and befriends the heroine

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for a full-color manhwa/manga.

It’s about a girl who woke up as the villainess of a story with red hair (I don’t know why she died) then as a teen she goes to a school, she befriends the heroine of the story. And three boys who are supposed to be in love with the heroine like her, one is like the main male lead in the original story, I think he has black hair and red eyes, he is like a noble or even a prince. And other is becoming a knight, and the last one is like a magician, he has silver hair.

The female lead has magical powers, and is really good.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Did you mean "three boys" or are the boys actually plants?  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: What did the heroine of the original story look like?

Answer (score 4):

Is this ***[Infatuation Unwanted](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/et7jv3v/infatuation-unwanted)***...?

> Plonked right into the world of a novel she once read, Sophie simply wishes to live out the rest of her quiet life in the background. Who could ask for a better place than the sleepy village of Pellun? And it was wonderful, peaceful...until knights came in searching for Lady Amelia. The Amelia Cedric from the most powerful noble family in the Rohatin Empire?! Wait, it can't be...I'm just an extra!
>
> [image]

The protagonist wakes up as Amelia Cedric, a minor character in a novel she once read. Amelia is a red-haired noblewoman with two brothers; a red-haired duke, Bastian (the head of the house), and Leonard, a silver-haired archmage. Her brothers have a sister complex and are infatuated with her. She subsequently acquires a third admirer in Caelus Elkadane, a powerful sorcerer with black hair and red eyes.

Amelia also has magical powers, and later in the story, begins taking lessons at a temple. Later still, she meets and befriends the female lead of the novel, Trisha, a blonde-haired princess.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be ***[I Don't Want to Be a Magpie Bridge](https://myanimelist.net/manga/154039/I_Dont_Want_to_Be_an_Ojakgyo)***...?

The main character is reincarnated into a novel she read in her previous life. She remembered her previous life when she was around six years old. Determined not to live the same life as the one in the novel, she takes up the sword to train to become a magical knight and, when she's older, she enters the kingdom's academy, where she befriends the heroine and gets mixed up with all of the male leads.

[image: Promotional image of "I Don't Want to Be a Magpie Bridge."]